# Remove duplicate rows in powerpivot

Tags: relationship, powerpivot, powerbi

When I create a relationship between two tables, it says each column has duplicate entries. 
How can I delete them? I just have to check my primary key column and remove rows of duplicate entires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would resolve this in the **Edit Queries** window.  Select your primary key column and from the **Home** ribbon, choose **Remove Rows / Remove Duplicates**.

If you have any interest in understanding what the duplicates are, you can investigate by using **Keep Rows / Keep Duplicates**.